Compile Zig using custom backend
Which flags shall I pass to zig compile-obj to have zig use its own code generation and linker thereby bypassing any calls to LLVM?
I've already tried a bunch of them but compilation is still slow (on par with clang).
Reason for asking is that I want to adjust the Zig-parts of https://github.com/nordlow/compiler-benchmark/ to make sure they use the fastest compilation path possible for zig build-obj and zig build-exe.

-fno-llvm -fno-lld -fno-clang
see https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/6251 (possibly 4 years out of date).

This is still 5-10x slower than D when compiling and building. Shouldn't Zig's build performance now be on par with D's when using custom backend and linker?
